# Windows 11 Explorer font size?

Tags: windows, windows-11

Is there a way to change only the font size of Windows Explorer on Win 11 ?

I don't want to use the Acessbility feature as it will change the font everywhere.

Comment: Sorry, you cannot.

Comment: You can use the Display scaling facilities - I do that and it change the Windows Explorer (and other) font sizes. Windows 10 , 11